# Launcher icons in an android app and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I desperately try to figure out what pictures to use for the launcher icon of an Android app created with Xamarin.Forms.

I found out, that the name of the icon file (without suffix) is given as an attribute to the `MainActivity` class:

```
[Activity(Label = "AndroidTestApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    ...
}
```

Then I read about the different icon sizes on the internet and created the following files, all named `icon.png`

- 48x48 px, 160 dpi, placed in folder `mipmap-mdpi`
- 72x72 px, 240 dpi, placed in folder `mipmap-hdpi`
- 96x96 px, 360 dpi, placed in folder `mipmap-xdpi`
- 144x144 px, 480 dpi, placed in folder `mipmap-xxdpi`
- 192x192 px, 640 dpi, placed in folder `mipmap-xxxdpi`

All the files have the Build Action `AndroidResource`.

In the first run all the files had a transparent background, but it seemed that Android used a default icon as launcher icon instead of my test icons.

Since I read that launcher Icons might not like transparent backgrounds, I created the same pictures with a wihite background in the second run, but Android doesn't show thes file either.

So, I'm looking for a clue what I might do wrong. Is it the png files itself? Is it the file names? Or the folders? Or none of the above?

The Xamarin.Forms documentation is quite sparse, no matter what I'm looking for (at least that's my first impression).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but creating a launcher icon on the internet (same sizes but apparently all files with 300 dpi), giving them another name and mentioning this name instead of `icon` at all the places where the old name was mentioned, did the trick. The new icons are shown now.

The only difference I can see (apart from the file name and the dpi value) is, that the not working image files (which have been added by default from the creation of the test project) have a custom tool called `MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles` mentioned in their properties which can't be removed. The newly added new image files don't have that.

Comment: Maybe your original image information wai incomplete or cropped.It also can result image can not show in android.So,suggest that try to use original source.

Comment: I created a plain png file with GIMP, that didn't work. I didn't do something fancy with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [this link](https://appicon.co/) to create different resolution of icons (only png) required for both android and iOS applications. If you are ready with the icons, add those icons in the drawable-xxxhdpi, xxhdpi, hdpi, and drawable of resources folder and not the mid folders. Once these files are added, you can set it in the Activity classes like below

[Activity(Label = "AndroidTestApp", Icon = **"@drawable/icon",** Theme = "@style/MainTheme",

Also make sure that you set icon in all the Activities you have to drawable/icon